# HttpSession tracking and monitoring tools

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jprofiler

I would like to track all HTTP sessions and all their attributes in a Java EE application.

Are there any freely available tools that I can use to monitor HTTP sessions? Can't I do it with JProfiler? If this can be done what are some tutorials that explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JProfiler, go to the heap walker and take a heap snapshot. Then change to the "Inspections" view of the heap walker and execute the inspection named "HTTP session objects". In the references view you will be able to see all session objects and you can inspect the attributes by opening the outgoing reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use JProfiler 7.  When I selected HTTP Session Object in the drop down tree in the "Inspections" as you have mentioned, there is nothing showing.But there is a button called " show calculated results in a new object set " and once it is clicked, a message pop out saying " No instances derived from javax.servlet.http.HttpSession in this set " . and there is no any other results showing session attributes. Have I gone in wrong way ? what is wrong ?

Comment: No that is correct. It means that no suitable objects whose classes are derived from HttpSession could be found in the profiled JVM.